# Symfony2 RESTful application - tests

Tags: php, rest, unit-testing, symfony

Which way is better to do tests in Symfony2 RESTful application or in any others applications.

Example:
I want to test `PostController`, which contains actions: `getPostsAction()`, `getPostAction()`, `putPostAction()`, `postPostAction()`, `deletePostAction()`.

So I've created `class PostControllerTest`.

Question is:

a) Should I create individual test for each action? Ex - testing updating:

- first load posts from fixture
- get id of one of this added posts
- update this post through `PostController@putPostAction`
- check updating result with entity manager

b) Or test few actions in one test(every through controller)? Ex:

- first test creating
- next listing(expecting added post)
- updating
- listing(expecting updated post)
- deleting
- listing(expecting 0 rows).

I think first option is OK, because I test only one controller action in one single test. I exactly know what I want to test.
But in second case I can do tests faster and don't need use fixtures and entity manager.

Which way will be better and why?

Answer (score 1):

I cannot say for sure what's the best solution for you but I think a good idea is to make it more functional as you said.
You can make your tests to follow a flow, like:

- Create user
- Update user
- Delete user

Making a complete cycle without leaving trash data.

I have an opensource project which I do exactly like this, and I also use some traits to help me on creating objects and validating responses from my Rest calls.
You can see a real test in here: https://github.com/renatomefidf/sammui/blob/master/src/Renatomefi/TranslateBundle/Tests/Controller/ManageControllerTest.php

By using the @depends annotation from phpunit you can determine the flow and make sure you have a logical path for your tests.

I hope this helps you, and if you have more questions let me know!